# Making a Header

Tags: header-footer

Can I ask some hints on how to make a letter head using LateX like [image: this one]

**Edit:** This is what I've tried.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\author{Emachine}
\title{}
\usepackage[paperwidth=936pt,paperheight=612pt,top=72pt,right=72pt,bottom=72pt,left=72pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=91pt]{MSU_Logo}\textbf{
\includegraphics[width=85pt]{CNSM_Logo} MINDANAO STATE UNIVERSITY}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\textbf{GENERAL SANTOS CITY}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\textbf{COLLEGE OF NATURAL SCIENCES AND MATHEMATICS}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\textbf{MATHEMATICS DEPARTMENT}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not at all clear from the body of the question that your only issue is with the positioning of the logos. Please edit the question to state that. Also, please make an initial attempt at this and show that in the way of a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: This can be done using `scrlttr2.cls` or `scrletter.sty`. See, e.g., [Reproducing the official header of the Washington State University](https://komascript.de/node/1599).

Comment: @Peter Grill I made an edit. Can you please see it now?

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot of your code; instead, post the code itself. Thanks.

Comment: Your example is not compilable, because we lack of the image files. Please replace them, e.g., by images of package `mwe`.

Comment: I am sorry for the post. This is my first time to ask in this site.

Comment: @jun: Where should this header appear within your document? Just on the first page, or on all pages?

Comment: @Werner Only at the first page.

Comment: @Werner Its okay for me if you replace those two logos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might get you started:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

{%
\centering\sffamily
\includegraphics[height=5\normalbaselineskip,valign=t]{example-image-a} \quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{ c }
  MINDANAO STATE UNIVERSITY \\
  GENERAL SANTOS CITY \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
  COLLEGE OF NATURAL SCIENCES AND MATHEMATICS \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
  MATHEMATICS DEPARTMENT
\end{tabular}\quad
\includegraphics[height=5\normalbaselineskip,valign=t]{example-image-b}
\par}

\bigskip

Some regular text \ldots

\end{document}
```

[`adjustbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) adds the `valign` key-value option to [`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\includegraphics` when using the `export` package load option.